# ADFS 2.0, SSO and SAML 2.0

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

This is a classic example of too much information = too much confusion.
I have a ASP.NET web application that uses the usual POST form authentication and would like to implement SSO.
Since we're a Microsoft shop we will use the ADFS 2.0. In order to implement SSO I understand that I will need to have also WIF to process SAML requests? 
Do I install the WIF under the same server as the ADFS?

I still want to re-direct failed SSO requests or non SSO requests to use the form, how do I handle this?

Can someone please describe the flow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using SAML to some 3rd party STS?

WIF (out the box) does not support SAML.

There is a WIF SAML extension but this is only CTP (Community Technology Preview) at this point.

WIF is integrated with your ASP.NET application. For .NET 4 and below, there is a separate download. For .NET 4.5, it's integrated.

WIF is just a set of .NET classes inside your application.

You integrate WIF with your ASP.NET application using a tool called FedUtil which is part of the WIF SDK download. (Invoked by "Add STS" inside VS).

The ADFS install installs WIF on the server but this is seperate to your application.

The flow is:

.NET Application --> (WIF) --> (WS-Federation) --> ADFS --> (SAML) --> STS

Comment: Correct, our web app is being accessed by clients, so just so I'm clear - WIF will handle the SAML inside the webapp and ADFS is just there to redirect valid SSO requests?

Comment: No - WIF doesn't handle SAML - ADFS converts the WIF WS-Federation message to SAML and sends to your STS.

Comment: So Using this example:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-federation-wif-application-step-by-step-guide(v=ws.10).aspx
I see only a 'success' scenario, where and how do I handle a 'failed' scenario - i.e. SAML did not pass authentication.

Comment: If you can't authenticate, ADFS displays an error on the login page. If you can authenticate but don't have permission for that page, WIF will display "Access Denied".

Comment: Ok thanks.
On that same issue - where do I define the query to verify against the SQL server? All I see in ADFS 2.0 manager is connection string.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Where does the SQL server come in? This sounds like a separate issue - probably best to start up another question.

Comment: It's in the same 'area'. Let me explain again - I have web application on one server and ADFS on a different one. 
A request is made to the web app (SAML) containing user info, this is redirected to the ADFS server for verification, however I don't wish this to be check against AD but against SQL server (where I will store the user info) - where do I make that connection?

Comment: Do you want to authenticate against credentials in AD or in SQL Server? Or do you just want to get claims from SQL Server after authentication? AD ONLY authenticates against AD. If you want to authenticate against SQL Server use https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v1. There's a v2 as well for .NET 4. If you just want claims http://www.idmcrisis.com/post/2011/11/30/Using-ADFS-20-SQL-Attribute-Store-for-%E2%80%9Cadvanced%E2%80%9D-claims.aspx

Comment: Well the flow will be that i will get email address inside the SAML request, I will need to parse the SAML to extract the value and verify that this email exists in SQL server - if so then the user automatically authenticated. Where does this fall under - claim or authentication? also - where in ADFS configuration I make sure to accept SAML requests from specific source?

Comment: If you have the SAML token, you are already authenticated. When you configure ADFS with the sp.xml RP metadata, it configures an identifier. Only SAML requests that contain that identifier will be processed,

Answer (score 2):

ADFS Supports two protocol for authenication.
1) WS-Federation Protocol
2) Web SSO SAML Protocol

****In Ws-Federation scenario****
For SSO between your Application and ADFS (Build trust relationship).

```
1)  Install ADFS & WIF on one server , Create some users in AD. 

2) Generate Federation Metadata.xml file in ADFS, save it one place for
future need. 

3)  Use Windows Azure Access Control Service(ACS) for
simplicity. (It will do all heavy lifting of your  authentication
process of token coming from ADFS) 

4)  Generate Federation
Metadata.xml file in ACS and Import in your ADFS server as relying
party. (give some claims as well)
```

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/06/25/using-federation-metadata-to-establish-a-relying-party-trust-in-ad-fs-2-0.aspx?Redirected=true][1]

```
5)  Import federation metadata.xml
file from ADFS server to ACS and Add it as Identity provider. (add
claim processing rule) 

6)  Now in your web Application use WIF
FedUtil Tool and import ACS federation metadata.xml file.
```

That's it.. you are good to go..

For Web SSO SAML protocol you have to do manual job of coding.

UseCase:

1. User will hit your application.
2. User is not authenticated so he will go to ACS and ACS will redirect it to ADFS login page.
3. User enters credentials. ADFS issue token to ACS with some claims. ACS will
   transform incoming ADFS claims and give it to your application.
4. your application is now authenticated so you can use claims and do
   authorization stuff.

**You can use URL scheme to check where this request should go to your forms authentication or ADFS authentication.**
eg. : http://somedomain.com/forms or http://somedomain.com/ADFS