# Wait for redirect, read form then post

Tags: java, android, redirect, https, request

I made an app that basically just posts a form to login then gets data using an API. Now the website it's for changed the way it works so that when you load the login page it redirects you to one with a random string in the query string and a different random string in the form action.

Since I can't just do an HTTPS POST request to the submit page anymore I need a way to load the login page, wait for the redirect and then wait for load again and then use the form action as HTTPS POST URL.

How do I load a page, specifically wait for it to redirect and then be done loading?

What I'm using now is pretty much this:

```
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

        String urlParameters = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UsernameTextBox="+ URLEncoder.encode(inumber, "UTF-8") + "&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PasswordTextBox="+ URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Comment: Is it a redirect done in HTML/JavaScript in the response from the POST or an HTTP 30X redirect?

Comment: That can be determined in a tool like the Firefox Developer Tools or the Chrome Inspector's network tab.

Comment: On load it returns a 302 and a Location. As far as I can tell what they're using is pretty much the title of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920990/adfs-2-0-sso-and-saml-2-0) question

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. use [HTTPURLConnection#setInstanceFollowRedirects(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects(boolean)) and ensure that you request the initial page with the same protocol as the redirect (it won't follow otherwise)
2. use [Google HTTP Client] which supports arbitrary redirects

Comment: Thanks, will look into the first one and see where that lands me and if that doesn't work I'll try the second option